# Type 'bower' in the CLI, have it run the local version from the current directory?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, bower

I have several unrelated projects that use `bower`.

I'm wondering if it is better to install `bower` globally or locally.

In the ‘global’ case, if a project upgrades bower to a newer version that has  breaking changes (e.g. no longer supported flags), all other projects may be impacted.

In the local-only case, you get project isolation, but in the CLI, instead of just

`> bower install`

you have to run

`> node ./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install`

which is a keyboard-full.

For other node tools (e.g. grunt, karma) there exist separate globally-installable packages (grunt-cli, karma-cli) that:

- are runnable from anywhere
- are just simple .cmd files
- look at the CWD and pick the *local* version of grunt/karma, and run *that* with the original parameters

...so you get the best of both worlds.

For bower, strangely, there is no bower-cli package.

Any idea why?

And, more to the point, is there a (simple) way to have the `bower` command runnable from anywhere, but targeting the bower version installed at the current working directory?

BTW, I'm on Windows.

Comment: There is a good practice to install everything locally and then wrap all binary calls with `npm run <smth>` (by adding appropriate script to `package.json`). Npm will always run binary from the locally installed package. With this approach all dependencies will be encapsulated with your project and there will be no need to install anything globally. And you will be sure that single `npm install` will install everything you need.

Comment: Some developers (including myself) even add `./node_modules/.bin` folder to their `$PATH`, forcing terminal to behave in the same matter as `npm run` (i.e. to look for locally installed binaries first).